# Script shutdown a computer with gpo

Tags: windows-xp, scripting

I have windows server 2003 domain and windows xp workstation. it is necessary that at 6.00 pm on computer was displayed a window (Do you really want to shutdown a computer and Yes/no button).If user click Yes or еxpired 5 minutes computer shutdown, else user click No than appears after an hour window will display again.

Comment: please don't crosspost to multiple sites. This is the correct site for this question per http://serverfault.com/faq

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Sysinternal's](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) [`pssshutdown`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx), in conjuction with the Windows `at` command you can create a daily scheduled task to perform this.  The utility allows for customized message box, default time out and presents a window prompting the user to cancel or continue the shutdown.

Create a Group Policy with a Computer Logon script something like:

```
REM Schedule computer shutdown task using AT.
SET SHUTDOWNTIME=22:00
SET TIMEOUT=600

IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES%\PStools\psshutdown.exe" (
    REM Clear at tasks
    AT.EXE /delete /yes
    REM Schedule shutdown daily, repeat in case of user cancellation.
    AT.EXE %SHUTDOWNTIME% /EVERY:m,t,w,th,f,s,su "%PROGRAMFILES%\PStools\psshutdown.exe" -accepteula -c -f -k -t %TIMEOUT% -m "Nightly shutdown in progress.  Click CANCEL if you need to continue using this computer."
)
```

You will need to customize the path to `psshutdown` to match your environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **at** and **shutdown.exe** commands in a script to accomplish this.

Comment: There's no way for a user to easily cancel the shutdown.