# Utility to allow users to postpone reboot?

Tags: windows, domain, users

Does anyone know of a utility that will allow a user to postpone a reboot on their PC to safely save their work?

I came across something today called "Safe Reboot" and it displayed a message saying your IT Administrator would like to reboot your computer and it will count the time in seconds.
The user had an option to extend the time by 3 minutes.

I am having trouble finding the name of the utility using Google.

Comment: You can do this with SysInternal's [`psshutdown`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541) utility.  See also: http://serverfault.com/questions/137592/script-shutdown-a-computer-with-gpo

Comment: Why is there computer arbitrarily rebooting in the first place?

Comment: My guess would be do to patching.

Comment: If this reboot is being triggered by updates, wouldn't it make more sense to use more appropriate update settings?

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt (windows+R and enter "cmd" in the run box as an administrator or power user) and enter:

```
Shutdown -a
```

This will "abort" an automated or scheduled shutdown or reboot.

Below is the full syntax for the shutdown command:

Syntax

shutdown [{-l|-s|-r|-a}] [-f] [-m [\ComputerName]] [-t xx] [-c "message"] [-d[u][p]:xx:yy]

Parameters
-l : Logs off the current user, this is also the defualt. -m ComputerName takes precedence.

-s : Shuts down the local computer.

-r : Reboots after shutdown.

**-a : Aborts shutdown. Ignores other parameters, except -l and ComputerName. You can only use -a during the time-out period.**

-f : Forces running applications to close.

-m [\ComputerName] : Specifies the computer that you want to shut down.

-t xx : Sets the timer for system shutdown in xx seconds. The default is 20 seconds.

-c "message" : Specifies a message to be displayed in the Message area of the System Shutdown window. You can use a maximum of 127 characters. You must enclose the message in quotation marks.

-d [u][p]:xx:yy : Lists the reason code for the shutdown. The following table lists the different values.

Value   Description
u
Indicates a user code.
p
Indicates a planned shutdown code.
xx
Specifies the major reason code (0-255).
yy
Specifies the minor reason code (0-65536).
/? : Displays help at the command prompt.

Comment: Hmm, not exactly user friendly, I don't know of many users who could manage this easily

Comment: Sorry, @Mark Still getting used to the mini-markdowns! The admin or user could Open Notepad and enter     "shutdown -a"   then Save-as filename "AbortShutdown.cmd" and choose file type "all files" from the dropdown.